# why settings automatically change to "Hide protected operation system files"

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, bitdefender

I have BitDefender (With last update) on my Windows-7.

I want to see hidden files, so from `Tools > Folder Options > View` , I change the settings as below, and click on OK:

[image]

But I can't see hidden files. when I double check the Options, I see the settings changed automatically as below :

[image]

I know this is a virus-like application! checking by a virus total via ProcessExplorer didn't help :

[image]

How can I understand with process is related to this issue?

Comment: Verify this isn't a bit defender feature

Comment: Note that when malware hides itself, it is unlikely to use the hidden file attribute, and instead use another more sophisticated form of cloaking. this is what rootkits excel at.

Comment: @FrankThomas How can I understand which process is the origin of this auto change setting?

Comment: can you change the hidden state using the reg hack here? http://techrena.net/show-hidden-files-and-folders-missing-windows-7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from Microsoft to see which process is setting the following registry value to 0.  Simply run it before enabling the ability to see protect operating system files and then search the output for the below registry key to see which process reverts it back to 0.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced "ShowSuperHidden"
```

In my tests, this does not appear to be a "feature" of BitDefender.

Answer (score 0):

It is Bitdefender, more specifically  *BitDefender Active Virus Control Usermode Filtering Library.* 
**Module:** avcuf64.dll. 
Once I've uninstalled  BitDefender I was able to set the folder permissions again, so I am  100% sure it was the culprit.